# AnimatedSize not tweening unless if there's parent widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I observe there is no tweening unless if an `AnimatedSize` widget has a parent `Container`. In the below code, the square goes to size zero if you tap on the square. If I remove the `AnimatedSize` widget's parent, the widget immediately goes to size zero without tweening. Furthermore, there is no tweening if I keep the parent `Container` but remove the `color` field or make it transparent.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  double _size = 200.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => setState(() {
        _size = 0;
      }),
      child: Container( // No tweening if this widget is removed
        color: Colors.red, // No tweening if this field is removed or made transparent
        child: AnimatedSize(
            curve: Curves.easeIn,
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
            child: Container(
              width: _size,
              height: _size,
              color: Colors.red,
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Why is the parent widget needed? Ideally I would like the tweening to happen without the need of this parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `TweenAnimationBuilder` I didn't need the outer widget::

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  double _endSize = 200.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => setState(() {
        _endSize = 0;
      }),
      child: TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 200.0, end: _endSize),
          curve: Curves.easeIn,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
          builder: (context, size, child) {
            return Container(
              width: size,
              height: size,
              color: Colors.red,
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```